# How to use Stored Procedures in SharePoint 2010, building custom solutions

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sharepoint, sql-server-2012, sharepoint-2010

I am looking forward in creating two solutions in my SharePoint 2010 environment using Sql Server 2012. I want to build solutions which use stored procedures, any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Its a quite broad question, but maybe this will help you get started : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jysaikia/archive/2010/12/15/a-step-by-step-guide-in-designing-bcs-entities-by-using-a-sql-stored-procedure.aspx

Comment: Solutions built using SharePoint cannot involve any type of customization of the underlying SQL Server database used by SharePoint, including adding or modifying stored procedures, without putting your environment into an unsupported state.